# How to fix blurry logo on phone devices?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My logo is showing up as blurry on mobile devices but looks fine on desktops.

Here is my markup:

```
          <div className="w-50per lAlign ">
            <Link to="/">
              <img
                src={require("../../assets/logo/logo.svg")}
                className={
                  props.currentViewPort === "TABLET" ? "LogoTablet" : "Logo"
                }
                alt="logo"
              />
            </Link>
          </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
          .logo{
              grid-area: logo;
              height: 70px;
              width: 210px;
           }

           .w-50per{
              width: 50%;
           }
           
           .lAlign{
              text-align: left;
           }
```

Comment: Can you make an example in the sandbox?

Comment: Mobile devices typically have much higher ppi than desktops, which can make images look blurry. If you've ever looked into mobile dev, you'll know that iOS has 2x and 3x images and Android has mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, and so on for this reason. An easy fix for your problem would be to just have a higher resolution version of your image display for mobile devices.